# emacs - stop adding indentation to current and next line when pressing RET

Tags: emacs, indentation, major-mode

I have a file open called `test.scss`, and when I press RET on a line, emacs will add 2 spaces to the current line and 4 extra spaces to the next line.

I've highlighted what the file looks like with `whitespace-mode`.

### **before pressing RET**

[image]

### **after pressing RET**

[image]

You can see that the `.my-element` row was auto-indented by 2 spaces, and the new line is indented by 4 spaces too many.

I want the output to look like this instead

### **desired output**

[image]

What can I do to make emacs produce my desired output?

Here is the output of `describe-mode`:

```
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption                 
Electric-Indent File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Eldoc                                
Global-Font-Lock Line-Number Menu-Bar Tooltip Whitespace                               

(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)

SCSS mode defined in `css-mode.el':
Major mode to edit "Sassy CSS" files.

In addition to any hooks its parent mode `css-mode' might have run,
this mode runs the hook `scss-mode-hook', as the final step
during initialization.
```

Although in this case I'm in scss-mode, I see similar behavior with most of the other modes I use, such as `ruby-mode`, `sgml-mode`, `js.el` mode and others. I'd like to make the behavior match the **desired output** shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Each mode can handle indentation in its own way, and you may have to look for mode-specific settings to get two-space indentation working everywhere.

For starters, you can set `css-indent-offset`, which should cover `css-mode` and `scss-mode`:

```
(setq css-indent-offset 2)
```

You can set the basic indenting of many other modes similarly. `ruby-mode` seems to use `ruby-indent-level`, `sgml-mode` uses `sgml-basic-offset`, and `js-mode` uses `js-indent-level`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to override the indent level for all modes to 2? Or better yet, automatically detect the indent of the file and use that as the indent level?

Comment: @mark, some similar languages inherit indentation settings from each other. For example, many modes for languages with C-like syntax respect `c-basic-offset`. You could try setting that and seeing what happens; it may work for `js-mode`, but I wouldn't bet on it for the others. In general, major modes are not required to respect a global indentation setting, and you may need to configure them individually.

Comment: I've found a nice little utility to detect indentation and set it appropriately for many modes https://github.com/jscheid/dtrt-indent

Comment: Since (s)css-mode uses SMIE, you can use `M-x smie-config-guess`.